# C# Operator == Cannot be applied : dlg.showDialog == System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

on the following if condition block for WPF C# project, the error received in syntax: **"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of bool? and System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult"**

```
 if (dlg.ShowDialog()   == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
               Logic......
            }
```

whats wrong with the code? I'm using VS2013

Comment: What type is `dlg` ?  (BTW WPF is not WinForms, you seem to be confusing the two).

Comment: what's your logic behind it?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to mix WPF and Windows Forms in your code, you should not do it!

In WPF `ShowDialog` method returns `bool?` (if `dlg` is `DialogBox` or `DialogWindow`)

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true) //or ==false, or ==null
{
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2), WPF ShowDialog return bool, according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) WinForms returns DialogResult.

It seems you are mixing UI components.